# Dspace installation porblem

Tags: maven

I tried to install dspace on my ubuntu server 14.04 things were going correctly until I tried the code mvn -U clean package the following error resulted and I am stuck at here, please provide me solutions.

```sh
$ mvn -U clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.095s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 19 23:14:44 BDT 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/dspace). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says "there is no POM in this directory", so you probably started Maven in a directory that has no `pom.xml`.

You cannot run `package` without as `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thank you for indicating the problem I edited pom.xml file someone suggested to erase some code from pom.xml are

Comment: Thank you for indicating the problem I edited pom.xml file dspace geek to erase some code from pom.xml are
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
.....
<phase>validate</phase>
<goals>
<goal>create</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

I deleted accordingly, I followed installation process 
https://wiki.lib.sun.ac.za/index.php/SUNScholar/Install_Ubuntu/S03/DSpace_User 
the apache tomcat success on my borwser when started mvn package the error output came please help me with your knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. The error says that you have no `pom.xml`. It does not talk about the content of the `pom.xml`, it just says that isn't any.

Comment: please help i have once again failed in ubuntu server 18.04 i have the although I have the pom.xml , the build is failure, please give me appropriate guideline that I can install step by step. pleae

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know _why_ you have no `pom.xml` in the directory, but obviously, this is the case. It does not help if you say "I have the pom.xml". Then you probably are in the wrong directory.

Comment: Thanks I get a clue now to follow the correct path, I once again have started to install it on ubuntu server 14.04 following installation guideline from https://wiki.lib.sun.ac.za/index.php/SUNScholar last time I launched tomcat on my browser it was success but later build failure, I will do accordingly again and will share my progress.